# Why border of the same thickness and same position don't completely overlap?

Tags: css

When you execute the code below in Firefox 64.0, the white border in the same thickness and same position as the black border protrudes slightly. I set the `top`,`left` property for the `position: absolute` element, but it did not help me.

Why is this white line outside the black border? How can we solve this problem?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #222;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

span::before {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Image of problem:

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: Anti-aliasing. By the way, in your example the border is not the same thickness.

Comment: Also read about pixel density if you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Mr Lister said, This is due to anti-aliasing, but I will try to explain *why* this creates the effect you see.  In a nutshell, if you have a diagonal line of pixels, it will look like a "staircase" of squares and won't be pleasing to the eye. Anti-aliasing sets the colors of pixels around these rough/jagged edges to be similar to the color of the edges in order to make these edges appear smoother.  What you are seeing is the anti-aliasing of the white circle appearing underneath the black circle, sort of like a solar eclipse.

Here is a picture for reference (middle line is without anti-aliasing, right line is with anti-aliasing.):

[image]